# continuous testing of a C++ project on github with different Linux distros

Tags: distribution-choice, c++, testing

Is there any framework to automatically try to compile a C++ project on github.com on every commit made, similar to what http://jenkins-ci.org or http://travis-ci.org do for different compilers on an Ubuntu VM, but for different Linux distros and versions?
EDIT: Ideally this would be a service where one doesn't need to maintain the different distros as VMs, but does that on the cloud, like travis-ci does for Ubuntu VMs.

Comment: I'd be really really surprised if software like that were somehow "distro centric".  Just glancing at the jenkins page, it's obviously packaged for a bunch of distros.  It also looks like it's in java, which will work exactly the same on any reasonably normal linux. So you've already found what you are looking for.

Comment: Ideally this would be a service where one doesn't need to maintain the different distros as VMs, but does that on the cloud, like travis-ci does for Ubuntu VMs.

Answer (score 2):

[OpenSuSE Build Service](http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE%3aBuild_Service_Tutorial) supports automatic build for many distributions (opensuse, ubuntu, ...).

I heard that svn (or git) integration projects exist but I never used them.

P.S. `osc` can be fully controlled by command line, so you could easily write an svn post commit hook (or git equivalent) to start the compilation.

Comment: Thanks, I had a look at it, and it looks very promising. I am not sure in what format one has to upload the packages to compile and how to specify the compilation instructions though. I'll try to dig through the docs.